# Comparing value with comma separated values in select statement

Tags: sql

this is how my table looks like :

[image]

Now i want to retrieve Field1 for 'AAA'

I tried something like :

```
select Field1 from table where CommaSeparatedList='AAA'
```

But it didn't work.

So How can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select field1
from table
where ',' + replace(commaseparatedlist, ' ', '') + ',' like '%,AAA,%'
```

Comment: I forgot to add that there's one caveat - if some tokens contain embedded spaces, then these tokens cannot be found this way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try:

```
SELECT Field1 FROM table WHERE CommaSeparatedList LIKE '%AAA%'
```

Comment: what if there is 5th entry for AAAAA or AAAA

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the column to contain the value you are looking for, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Field1 
FROM table 
WHERE CommaSeparatedList LIKE '%AAA%'
```